# Cronjob doens't understand the code to execute?

Tags: php, cron

I have set up a cronjob which updates a bunch of contracts in a certain system. When I run the PHP-script in a browser it all works fine, but when the cronjob has to do the trick it fails. I'm kinda stuck on this one since I don't have a lot of experience with cronjobs (heck.. I can only set them up in DirectAdmin).

My PHP scripts has some includes to some classes, these includes work properly (i've tested it by sending mails to myself line by line). When the base-classes are included I have a class which handles autoloading. When I do something like Class::GetInstance() it fails.

My cronjob looks like:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/username/domains/domain/public_html/path/to/script.php
```

What can I do to fix this? Perhaps not run it via php, but by a browser or something? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I don't know this ;)

Comment: does the script run if you execute it from the command line?

Comment: does `/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/domains/domain/public_html/path/to/script.php` work when invoked from a normal shell ? points to check include: which user is used to run this ? is the environment setup correctly ? what about permissions ?

Comment: I'm not much of a CL-guy. How can I properly test this? @Yahia, I'm not sure, I think its the webuser from the hostingaccount? since the job is put there?

Comment: Maybe you've used some includes that need the path to be set correctly? if so: fix them to be absolute (no `../` etc), or put a "`cd /home/username/..etc.../path/`" in front of your call.

Comment: If you are using Cpanel, and when you view or edit files, then you can see the exact path of the files at top of browser. Using this path, it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remeber that when PHP is executed on CLI with `/usr/local/bin/php` you do not have the `$_SERVER` variable setted properly! I had that problem too because my script had to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. As said, try to run it in a normal shell to see if it works. Alternatively you can change your cronjob command to:

```
wget -q http://yourdomain.com/path/to/script.php
```

Usually this works well because it is just identical to fetch that URL from a normal browser.

`wget` man page here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget

Answer (score 0):

You can't always call the php file directly that expects to be called via HTTP. Judging from path, it's a part of website, which is normally executed by browser, hence I'ld set the cronjob up to not to be directly called by php-cli, but rather by doing a `curl` request to the website's URL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but wget seemed to be my solution.

Answer (score 0):

"it fails" is not the problem description one can call a suffucient one.

add this line in your crontab file

```
MAILTO=your@mail
```

and run your jobs.
You will get the script output and be able either to correct your code or ask a sensible question.

You may also redirect stdout and stderr to a log file

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried that without result.. :( wget did it for me.